# stackoverflow with FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory

Tags: java, hadoop

i need to use java URL to access files on hdfs : ive seen that i must use 
this :

`static {
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
}`

but, when i launch my program, i got a stackoverflow caused by this line.

Anyone has an idea to solve my issue?

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more context? What I am thinking of: A part of the stacktrace, the code that actually causes the exception (presumably the code doing an fs access) etc.

Comment: the stacktrace is very long (i think there's an infinite loop) but heres the begining 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:243)
 at java.io.File.exists(File.java:750)
 at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:999)
 at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:977)
 at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:162)'

Comment: the code that causes the exception is the one ive given in my first post and im using the URL in a xml file to configure an external tool.

Comment: The Stacktrace does not tell very much. To make sense out of a StackOverflowError search for patterns (the same method 1 calling the same method 2 calling the same method 3 etc. etc. calling the same method 1 again). And it would be good if you posted additional information in the post, not in the comments, because in the comments formatting does not work sooo well... :-)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360018/getting-stack-overflow-error-in-hadoop/21198191

Comment: ###see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360018/getting-stack-overflow-error-in-hadoop/21198191