# Getting stack overflow error in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am getting stack overflow error while accessing haddop file using java code.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
public class URLCat 
{
    static 
    {
            URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        InputStream in = null;
        try 
        {
            in = new URL(args[0]).openStream();
            IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
        }
        finally 
        {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }
    }
}
```

i used eclipse to debug this code then i came to know line

```
in = new URL(args[0]).openStream();
```

producing error.

I am runnung this code by passing hadoop file path i.e

```
 hdfs://localhost/user/jay/abc.txt
```

**Exception (pulled from comments) :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at java.nio.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:174) 
  at java.nio.ByteBuffer.<init>(ByteBuffer.java:259) 
  at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:52) 
  at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:350) 
  at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:373) 
  at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:237) 
  at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:272) 
  at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:946) 
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method) 
  .. stack trace truncated ..
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a stacktrace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.nio.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:174)
 at java.nio.ByteBuffer.<init>(ByteBuffer.java:259)
 at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:52)
 at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:350)
 at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:373)
 at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:237)
 at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:272)
 at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:946)
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
 at

Comment: From stack trace it doesnt seem to have error at the line which you said. Any other info you might want to add

Comment: add error with edit your question, not add in comment area

Comment: abhinav i have used java debugger to understand code flow that time i came to know that code is terminating after this line so i posted that line.

Answer (score 3):

1) This is because of the bug in the FSURLStreamHandlerFactory class provided by hadoop. Please note that the bug is fixed in the latest jar which contains this class.

2) This file is located in hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.2.1.jar. To understand the problem completely we have to understand how the java.net.URL class works.

### Working of URL object

When we create a new URL using any one of its constructor without passing "URLStreamHandler" (either through passing null for its value or calling constructor which does not take URLStreamHandler object as its parameter) then internally it calls a method called getURLStreamHandler(). This method returns the URLStreamHandler object and sets a member

variable in URL class.

This object knows how to construct a connection of a particular scheme like "http", "file"... and so on. This URLStreamHandler is constructed by the factory called

URLStreamHandlerFactory.

3) In the problem example given above the URLStreamHandlerFactory was set to "FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory" by calling the following static method.

```
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
```

So when we create a new URL then this "FSUrlStreamHandlerFactory" is used to create the URLStreamHandler object for this new URL by calling its createURLStreamHandler(protocol) method.

This method inturn calls a method called loadFileSystems() of FileSystem class. The loadFileSystems() method invokes the ServiceLoader.load("FileSystem.class") so it tries to read the binary names of the FileSystem implementation classes by searching all META-INF/services/*.FileSystem files of all jar files in classpath and reading its entries.

4) Remember that the each jar is handled as URL object meaning for each jar an URL object is created by the ClassLoader internally. The class loader supplies the URLStreamHandler object

when constructing the URL for these jars so these URLs will not be affected by the "FSUrlStreamHandlerFactory" we set because the URL has already having the "URLStreamHandler". Since we are

dealing with jar files the class loader sets the "URLStreamHandler" as of type "sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler".

5) Now inorder to read the entries inside the jar files for the FileSystem implementation classes the  "sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler" needs to construct the URL object for each entry by

calling the URL constructor without the URLStreamHandler object. Since we already defined the URLStreamHandlerFactory as "FSUrlStreamHandlerFactory" it calls the createURLStreamHandler

(protocol) method which causes to recurse indefinetly and lead to the "StackOverflowException".

This bug is known as the "HADOOP-9041" by the Hadoop committters. The link is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9041.

I know this is somewhat complicated.

So in short the solution to this problem is given below.

1) Use the latest jar hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.2.1.jar which has the fix for this bug

or

2) Put the following statement in the static block before setting the URLStreamHandlerFactory.

```
      static {
               FileSystem.getFileSystemClass("file",new Configuration()); 
               URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
             }
```

Note that the first statement inside the static block doesn't depend on FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory now and uses the default handler for file:// to read the file entires in META-INF/services/*.FileSystem files.

Answer (score 1):

I have a ***workaround.***

It would be great if someone more familiar with the current state of the Hadoop world (Jan 2014) would enlighten us and/or explain the behavior.

I encountered the same of StackOverflowError when trying to run URLCat from Haddop The Definitive Guide Third Edition Tom White

I have the problem with Cloudera QuickStart 4.4.0 and 4.3.0

Using both jdk1.6.0_32 and jdk1.6.0_45

The problem occurs during initializion/class loading of org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem underneath java.net.URL
There is some kind of recursive exception handling that is kicking in. 
I did the best I could to trace it down. 
The path leads to java.util.ServiceLoader which then invokes sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.nextElement()
Unfortunately, the source for sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration is **not** included in the jdk src.zip ... perhaps an oversight because it is in java package sun.misc

In an attempt to trigger the error through another execution path I came up with a workaround ...

You can avoid the conditions that lead to StackOverflowError by invoking org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(String, Configuration) prior to registering the StreamHandlerFactory.

This can be done by modifying the static initialization block (see original listing above):

```
   static {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        try {
            FileSystem.getFileSystemClass("file", conf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        };
        URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
    }
```

This can also be accomplished by moving the contents of this static block to your main().

I found another reference to this error from Aug 2011 at [stackoverflow with FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038292/stackoverflow-with-fsurlstreamhandlerfactory)

I am quite puzzled that more hadoop newbies have not stumbled onto this problem ... buy the Hadoop book ... download Cloudera QuickStart ... try a very simple example ... **FAIL!?**

Any insight from more experienced folks would be appreciated.