# malformedURLException : no protocol

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to execute a simple Hadoop program to read the contents of the file and print it on to the console.
I am following Hadoop The definitive guide : URLCat example

I am getting malformed URL Exception : no protocol

When i use -cat with hdfs://localhost/user/training/test.txt i am getting the contents printed out but when i use the same path while executing the jar i am getting the mentioned exception.

I have added static block where it sets the URLStreamHandlerFactory

EDITED :

My Program :

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;

// vv URLCat
public class URLCat {

  static {
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
      in = new URL(args[0]).openStream();
      IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
    } finally {
      IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "where it sets the URLStreamHandlerFactory"? We don't all have that book, so you're going to have to be more specific

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question by adding the program i have written.

Comment: Thanks, now, what are you giving for `args[0]`?

Comment: i am providing "hdfs://localhost/user/training/test.txt"

Comment: When i do hadoop fs -cat hdfs://localhost/user/training/test.txt , i am getting the contents of the file. so path is right.

Comment: Command that i am executing:
hadoop jar Hadoop-Examples.jar URLCat hdfs://localhost/user/training/test.txt

Output:
Exception in main thread : java.net.MalformedExceptionURLException : no protocol : URLCat

This is the exact error i am getting

Comment: I don't think you need `localhost`. You should be able to do `hdfs:///user/training/test.txt`. As well as `hdfs dfs -cat /user/training/test.txt`

Comment: I tried out without localhost. It am getting the same error. but with cat command the path is working fine.
i have a doubt : In the exception we need to get the URL or the path which we are passing right ? here it is coming as URLCat , the name of the class. I am providing the command properly ?

Comment: Is this related to your error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606679/how-can-i-run-hadoop-run-with-a-java-class

Comment: Yea it is related to this issue. But i am getting a different exception. I dunno where i am going wrong.

Comment: What if you don't use the static block and set the URL factory in the main method? I assume you haven't edited your core-site.xml or hdfs-site.xml?

Comment: Problem was the args pointer. I was passing the path through args[1] but i was using args[0] in the program.
however this dint gimme me the output , i had add one more line of code in static block like below :

    static {
                   FileSystem.getFileSystemClass("file",new Configuration()); 
                   URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
                 } 

Well explained in the below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360018/getting-stack-overflow-error-in-hadoop